# Use jQuery to target a class within a div and perform additional changes within the same div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="pack1">
    <a class="optionButton">First option</a>
    <a class="optionButton">Second option</a>
    <a class="optionButton">Third option</a>
</div>

<div class="pack2">
    <a class="optionButton">First option</a>
    <a class="optionButton">Second option</a>
    <a class="optionButton">Third option</a>
</div>

<div class="pack3">
    <a class="optionButton">First option</a>
    <a class="optionButton">Second option</a>
    <a class="optionButton">Third option</a>
</div>

[...]

<div class="pack10">
    <a class="optionButton">First option</a>
    <a class="optionButton">Second option</a>
    <a class="optionButton">Third option</a>
</div>
```

Using jQuery I would like to trigger an event on clicking the `a` tag with the `optionButton` class but I don't know how to limit the event to the div that the `a` tag resides in.

For example right now I have something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.optionButton').click(function() {
        $(".optionButton").removeClass('checked');
        $(this).addClass('checked');
    });
});
```

It works fine for the first selection, lets say when I click the `First option` in the `pack1` div, but if I make another selection, lets say `Third option` in the `pack3` div, the first one will disapear.

Also, there must be only one selected option for each pach.

Comment: $(this).parent().find(".optionButton").removeClass("checked");

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: I think @mhodges solution should work

Comment: I've created a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lb716udh/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because exact DOM structure is highly subject to change, your best bet is to almost always go to the parent and search your way down like so:

1) `$(this).parent().find(".optionButton").removeClass("checked");`

or you can simplify the selector results set (and make your code slightly more efficient) by saying:

2) `$(this).parent().find(".checked").removeClass("checked");`

You can also use the selector context parameter like so:

3) `$(".checked", $(this).parent()).removeClass("checked");`

The difference between 2 and 3 is purely syntactic. jQuery will convert 3 into 2 behind the scenes

Comment: Thanks for this solution. It works in the fiddle, but in the real code I get an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` error.

Comment: @Cosmin I can assure you that there is nothing syntactically wrong with any of the 3 lines of code I have provided. It's possible that you may have accidentally mis-copy/pasted or you have a syntax error elsewhere in your code

Answer (score 2):

You need to narrow down the selection of your `removeClass`, as right now it's selecting *every* occurrence of `optionButton`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.optionButton').click(function() {
        $(this).siblings('.optionButton').removeClass('checked');
        $(this).addClass('checked');
    });
});
```

This will narrow it down by selecting siblings of the clicked element that have the class `optionButton`.

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lb716udh/2/)

**EDIT:** Woops, put the wrong class in there. Should be patched up now.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.optionButton').click(function() {
        var parent = $(this).closest("div");//getting the parent content
        parent.find(".optionButton").removeClass('checked');//remove the checked
        $(this).addClass('checked');
    });
});
```